# Update a MongoDB array with Push and Slice

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a document in MongoDB that I want to update. In this example, I have a property (events.properties.color) that's an array with multiple (duplicate) values.

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d91fd51abe17b722ca9c82c"),  
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2019-09-30T13:04:15.077+0000"), 
    "title" : "My Old Car", 
    "version" : NumberInt(0) 
    "events" : [
        { 
            "properties" : {
                "color" : [
                    "red", 
                    "red", 
                    "red", 
                    "red"
                ]
            }, 
            "attributes" : {
                "MAKE" : "TOYOTA", 
                "MODEL" : "COROLLA", 
                "YEAR" : "1991", 
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to change this array to a string with a single value (red). For my data, I can assume that every value in the array is the same, so the value of the string can just be the first value in the array. 
I was trying to iterate through my collection with something like this:

```
db.getCollection('cars').update(
    [
        // Match array with >1 value
        { $match: { 'events.properties.color.2': {$exists: true} } },

        {
            //Slice to only include first value in array. 
            $push:{
                'events.$.properties.color':{
                    $each: [ ],
                    $slice: 1
                }
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

But I keep getting an error: "Need an object", which (I think) means that I'm not referencing the color array properly. Any ideas on what I should change? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you got a little mixed up with doing aggregation, when you want to do is an update. Made some minor corrections to your update, (removed the `[]` and `$match`):

```
db.books.update(
    // Match array with >1 value
    {'events.properties.color.2': {$exists: true}} ,
    {
        //Slice to only include first value in array. 
        $push:{
            'events.$.properties.color':{
                $each: [ ],
                $slice: 1
            }
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: That's it. Thanks!